# Sending a JSON request to ebay API

Tags: c#, json, ebay-api

Ok so I'm having a bit of trouble getting these JSON requests through to the Ebay API.

Here is the json request:

```
string jsonInventoryRequest = "{" +
                    "\"requests\": [";

        int commaCount = 1;
        foreach (var ep in productsToProcess)
        {
            jsonInventoryRequest += "{\"offers\": [{" +
                "\"availableQuantity\":" + ep.EbayProductStockQuantity + "," +
                "\"offerId\":\"" + ep.EbayID.ToString() + "\"," +
                "\"price\": {" +
                    "\"currency\": \"AUD\"," +
                    "\"value\":\"" + ep.EbayProductPrice.ToString() + "\"" +
                "}" +
            "}],";

            jsonInventoryRequest += "\"shipToLocationAvailability\": " + "{" +
                "\"quantity\":" + ep.EbayProductStockQuantity +
                "},";

            jsonInventoryRequest += "\"sku\": " + ep.EbayProductSKU.ToString() + "}";
            if (commaCount < productsToProcess.Count())
                jsonInventoryRequest += ",";

            commaCount++;
            sendEbayApiRequest = true;
        }

        jsonInventoryRequest += 
            "]" +
        "}";
```

And the `Debug.WriteLine()` output of the above JSON request is :

```
json string = {"requests": [{"offers": [{"availableQuantity":0,"offerId":"098772298312","price": {"currency": "AUD","value":"148.39"}}],"shipToLocationAvailability": {"quantity":0},"sku": 135779},{"offers": [{"availableQuantity":1,"offerId":"044211823133","price": {"currency": "AUD","value":"148.39"}}],"shipToLocationAvailability": {"quantity":1},"sku": 133607}]}
```

Here is the code in C# to send the request:

```
var ebayAppIdSetting = _settingService.GetSettingByKey(
                            "ebaysetting.appid", "");

        var ebayCertIdSetting = _settingService.GetSettingByKey(
                            "ebaysetting.certid", "");

        var ebayRuNameSetting = _settingService.GetSettingByKey(
                            "ebaysetting.appid", "");

        var stringToEncode = ebayAppIdSetting + ":" + ebayCertIdSetting;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncode);
        var base64string = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", base64string);

        var stringContent = "?grant_type=client_credentials&" + "redirect_uri=" + ebayRuNameSetting + "&scope=https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope";
        var requestBody = new StringContent(stringContent.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        requestBody.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var response = client.PostAsync("https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token", requestBody);
```

The output I get when I do `Debug.WriteLine("response.Content = " + response.Result);` is:

> response.Content = StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized',
>   Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {
>   RlogId:
>   t6ldssk%28ciudbq%60anng%7Fu2h%3F%3Cwk%7Difvqn*14%3F0513%29pqtfwpu%29pdhcaj%7E%29fgg%7E%606%28dlh-1613f3af633-0xbd
>   X-EBAY-C-REQUEST-ID: ri=HNOZE3cmCr94,rci=6kMHBw5dW0vMDp8A
>   X-EBAY-C-VERSION: 1.0.0   X-EBAY-REQUEST-ID:
>   1613f3af62e.a096c6b.25e7e.ffa2b377!/identity/v1/oauth2/!10.9.108.107!r1esbngcos[]!token.unknown_grant!10.9.107.168!r1oauth-envadvcdhidzs5k[]
>   Connection: keep-alive   Date: Mon, 29 Jan 2018 00:04:44 GMT
>   Set-Cookie: ebay=%5Esbf%3D%23%5E;Domain=.ebay.com;Path=/
>   WWW-Authenticate: Basic   Content-Length: 77   Content-Type:
>   application/json }

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong. Cheers

Comment: We are in 2018. JSON parsers and formatters have existed for years. You are not supposed to write JSON manually, never. That said, your problem is on the authentication side, not on the JSON sent.

Comment: Hi @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for helping. I'm still learning so I have no idea how to do it. Got an example handy.
Yeah I figured it was an error in authentication, but my credentials are correct and I have done everything right from what I can see. Would be nice if I could find an example

Comment: It would also be nice if you would stop adding language tags to your titles.  They are just noise and do nothing to explain the "problem"

Comment: Ok @Plutonix will try to remember that for next time

Comment: 401 means you are not authorized/authenticated. I guess you request is rejected even before the json payload is being read. You should use a library (e.g. JSON.Net) to handle your json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the authentication was failing because I was sending wrong authentication token. Needed to get oauth token from application tokens.

So instead of base64 encoding token like this:

```
var base64string = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", base64string);
```

I needed to do the following:

```
url = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/bulk_update_price_quantity";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.Method = "POST";
        //request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer **OAUTH TOKEN GOES HERE WITHOUT ASTERIKS**");

        // Send the request
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(jsonInventoryRequest);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        // Get the response
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        if (response != null)
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                // Parse the JSON response
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```